# Google AppEngine - Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' Unable to connect

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Every so often I receive the following errors in my logs. It appears to be happening during the following actions: `commit`, `lookup`, `runQuery`

**This is the start of each error:**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' with message 'HTTP Error: Unable to connect: 'fopen(https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/{APPENGINE_ID}/commit): failed to open stream: Unsupported SSL context options are set. The following options are present, but have been ignored: cafile

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' with message 'HTTP Error: Unable to connect: 'fopen(https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/{APPENGINE_ID}/lookup): failed to open stream: Unsupported SSL context options are set. The following options are present, but have been ignored: cafile

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_IO_Exception' with message 'HTTP Error: Unable to connect: 'fopen(https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/{APPENGINE_ID}/runQuery): failed to open stream: Unsupported SSL context options are set. The following options are present, but have been ignored: cafile
```

**And this is the exact text below each of the above errors:**

```
Fetch error'' in /base/data/home/apps/{APPENGINE_ID}/{NUMBERS}/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/IO/Stream.php:141
Stack trace:
#0 /base/data/home/apps/{APPENGINE_ID}/{NUMBERS}/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/IO/Abstract.php(136): Google_IO_Stream->executeRequest(Object(Google_Http_Request))
#1 /base/data/home/apps/{APPENGINE_ID}/{NUMBERS}/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(60): Google_IO_Abstract->makeRequest(Object(Google_Http_Request))
#2 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
#3 /base/data/home/apps/{APPENGINE_ID}/{NUMBERS}/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Task/Runne in /base/data/home/apps/{APPENGINE_ID}/{NUMBERS}/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/IO/Stream.php on line 141
```

Does anyone know why this might be occurring? This doesn't happen all the time so I seriously doubt it has anything to do my code.

[Bug Report Link](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12005)